Identifying toll roads on Apple Maps
Using Apple Maps on my Mac, I’m trying to plan a driving trip interstate. I’ve entered all the stops.
The only thing is that there will be a few toll roads on the way. No problem, but I would like to know where these toll roads will be so that I can organise toll payment options.
I can’t find anything on either the map or directions which specify where the toll roads are. It just mentions that there are tolls somewhere.
Is there a way of identifying the actual toll roads?

Apple Maps has a function to avoid toll roads, but does not support viewing which specific roads require tolls or how much they cost.
Some third party apps can help you plan out toll costs in advance, but as of writing this, it is not natively baked into Apple Maps just yet.
